# How to apply condition to Shell navigation?

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

I have a .Net MAUI app with CommunityToolkit.Mvvm that uses shell nagivation:

```
<FlyoutItem> 
    ...
    <ShellContent Title="Video Chat"
                  Icon="{StaticResource IconVideoChat}"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate videoChat:VideoChatPage}"
                  FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" 
                  IsVisible="{Binding IsVideoChatVisible}" />
    ...
</FlyoutItem>
```

Upon clicking on this item, VideoChatPage opens. I need before opening that page to check if the user is logged in, and if not, let them do it. If the user fails to do it (cancels from the login screen), the page should not open. How can I do that? How can I intercept the shell item click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override AppShell OnNavigating method to achieve this.

```
protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigating(args);
    if (Any Condition)
    {
        //Then won't navigate
        args.Cancel();
    }
}
```

To get the next page, you may use `args.Target.Location.OriginalString`.

First you could set a **Route** for a FlyoutItem (this time set it to 'Home'):

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home">
   <Tab>
       <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Route="Home" />
   </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Then you may check the `args.Target.Location.OriginalString`.

```
protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigating(args);
    // if navigate to "Home/MainPage", then it is true
    if (args.Target.Location.OriginalString.Contains("Home"))
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To use it, I need to know what the page I am navigating to for making the condition. Could you please help, as I am not finding a way to determine that.

Comment: I do see how to find out the current page, but not the next page.

Comment: Please see my updates. I use ```args.Target.Location.OriginalString``` to get the next page.